# xquery for conditional path

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a problem dealing with xquery, I have different type of nodes at the same level. I need to display an xquery depending on the node. Following is the example

```
   <head>
         <type1>
              <name>abc</name>
         </type1>
         <type2>
               <name>def</name>
               <type1>
                      <name>efg</name>
               </type1>
         </type2>
   </head>
```

Now I would like to perform an xquery where the name tag has to be checked. like if name is "def" then result should be

```
  <type1>
                <name> efg </name>
   </type1>
```

Can you please direct me to work on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cone be done in a simple XPath (XPath is a subset of XQuery). The expression will be:

```
//*[name = 'def']/type1
```

This searches for all elements with a child element named `name` equal to `def` and returns the `type1` element. Depending on your actual data you might want to change `*` (a wildcard operator) to `type2`, if you just want to search in `type2` elements. This is not quite clear from your question.

You might also want to check the basics of XPath/XQuery as this is one of the most basic things. So if you intend to spend more time using XPath/XQuery you should make yourself more familiar with the language.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am looking for a query which prints everything all the siblings and descendents, when a name matches with def. I understand I can use following to display everything that follows

Comment: @user2934433 Please be more specific and provide more information what you actually want to achieve. If you want to show all siblings and descendants, why is `<name>def</name>` not in your output set?